# How might teleportation to or from a place far from a teleportation device work?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction, physics, teleportation

In many science fiction television shows, and movies characters are teleported from the space ship to a planet, and vice verse, even though the planet has no teleportation device on it's surface, and there may be kilometers of air, or in some cases, even some rock between the space ship teleportation device, and the site that characters are arriving to or leaving from, on the planet.

One method of teleportation would be to use a teleportation device to simultaneously scan, and deconstruct a person, then beam the information needed to reconstruct the person to another teleportation device, that then reconstructs the person using atoms and molecules that are already at this location.

If instead the person was deconstructed and scanned, or reconstructed when the person is underground and the teleportation device is on a space ship in orbit, then there could be multiple meters of solid rock between the person and the space ship.

How might scanning, deconstructing, and reconstructing a person work when there is solid rock, or kilometers of atmosphere, or even just a great distance between the teleportation device and the person?

Comment: Are you asking us to explain how a fictional apparatus works?  If you think about it, anyone with even a half-science-based answer should be running to the patent office, not posting it as an answer.  Are you simply asking for a rationalization of why the transport beam can seemingly penetrate (almost) any material?  How would you judge the best answer?  [VTC OT:POB](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#643).